# Need to know if a jQuery UI Widget has been applied to a DOM object

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, widget, progress-bar

I'm using jQuery and have some interactions with a jQuery UI where I need to get options.  However there's a possibility that the jQuery UI function has not been applied yet to the DOM object. I'm getting a JavaScript error right now when I access an option.

I have a DOM object that has the progressbar (http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar) attached to it (maybe). In another thread, I'm trying to access the options using  `domObj.progressbar("option", "value")`.

How do I determine if that `domObj` has a `progressbar` attached?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DOM object will get an extra CSS class appended to it: "ui-progressbar". If you View Source on http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar then you can see a div with id=progressbar and nothing more, but if you use Firebug and click the element you can see it has a few more classed added.

Edited: I think that @jamiebarrow's solution is the more correct one here.

Comment: Ok, on my custom ui widget, I'll just add a class to the dom object and check for it.  Thanks a bunch for the idea

Answer (score 25):

You can access the progress bar object on the element by doing:

```
$("#myid").data("progressbar")
```

So to use this:

```
var progressBar = $("#myid").data("progressbar");
if ( progressBar == null ) {
    // handle case when no progressbar is setup for my selector
} else {
    alert("The value is: " + progressBar.value());
}
```

Comment: I think this way is more elegant than colinramsay's suggestion. It's also applicable to other plugins that store their 'API objects' using the jQuery data function. And using the Firebug console to inspect what $("#myid").data() returns is very useful :)

Comment: I thought so too, except that the way jQuery handles namespace separators clearly makes this smell like an implementation detail. The HOWTO says 'the name of the plugin must include a namespace' https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/ This doesn't seem to actually be true, but when we follow that advice, the full stop in the widget name is replaced by camelcase. So `$.widget('my_namespace.foo')` becomes `data('my_namespaceFoo')`. I believe that it otherwise makes all letters lowercase, too, so it can be cryptic to work out the name of the data element.

Comment: To elaborate on the camelcase point: I extended a widget, and if the widget name is "myselectmenu", then an element with id=elid can be tested with $("#elid").data("customMyselectmenu") ... but not sure if this can be relied on in future versions of jquery-ui.

Answer (score 11):

As of jQuery UI 1.11, widgets can be directly tested for via the `instance` method:

```
var hasProgressbar = ($(element).progressbar("instance") !== undefined);
```

Documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/#method-instance

Comment: this sould be the correct answer since its valid for every widget.

Answer (score 10):

According to [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jquery-ui/iIAAONDiXfg), the recommended way to detect if a widget has been rendered on an element is as follows:

```
var hasWidget = $('selector').is(':ui-widgetname');
```

Comment: Same thing Colin said way back in 2009 in the answer I accepted. However, your code is very succinct.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer to use hasOwnProperty on any object in JavaScript, since it returns a boolean every time.

```
var hasWidget = $( "selector-here" ).data().hasOwnProperty( "widget-name-here" );
if ( hasWidget )
{
    // Put your awesome code here.
}
```

Which IMHO is a little better than checking null; what if it switches to undefined, which, also IMO is what it should return.

Comment: On second thought, I would actually keep my code the way it is now, but rather do the check on the truthy/falsy value of progressBar (so rather have `if (!progressBar)`). It makes sense to me that I pass in a parameter to `data()` and get back an object. Could probably also check the type of it is an object, but I dunno, seems like a lot of checking for something that's pretty well defined... guess it depends ;)