# When using jqueryUI buttonset, is there anyway to determine if it has been initialized?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqueryi-ui-buttonset

I have jQuery code that refreshes a button set:

```
$("#myRadio").buttonset('refresh');
```

But I found a use case where it's being called prior to this line:

```
$("#myRadio").buttonset();
```

And then blowing up because its not initialized. I wanted to see if there is a way to determine if this buttonset() initialization has happened so I can check before calling refersh:

Something like:

```
if($("#myRadio").buttonsetIsInitialized())
{
    $("#myRadio").buttonset('refresh');
}
```

What is the correct way to do this check?

Comment: Related, possibly dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1505270/need-to-know-if-a-jquery-ui-widget-has-been-applied-to-a-dom-object?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: This is a common problem with plugin initialisation, but the solution is not to test if it has been initialised, but to find out why your sequencing is wrong in the first place. Please provide more of your code for a correct answer (instead of a work-around) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/JME7x/44/)**.

You could do it same way as you described in your OP by adding new method `buttonsetIsInitialized()` to the jQuery object :

```
$.fn.buttonsetIsInitialized = function () {
    return this.hasClass('ui-buttonset');
};
```

This method will check if the class `ui-buttonset` (that the instantiation add to element) is present in element class list.

```
if($("#myRadio").buttonsetIsInitialized()){
    $("#myRadio").buttonset('refresh');
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Not initialized case:**

```js
$.fn.buttonsetIsInitialized = function () {
  return this.hasClass('ui-buttonset');
};

if( $("#myRadio").buttonsetIsInitialized() ){
  console.log('Refresh element');
}else{
  console.log('Not initialized');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="myRadio">
  <input id="first" type="radio" value="1" name="steps"/><label for="first">First</label>
  <input id="second" type="radio" value="2" name="steps"/><label for="second">Second</label>
</div>
```

**Initialized case:**

```js
$('#myRadio').buttonset(); //Initilized

$.fn.buttonsetIsInitialized = function () {
  return this.hasClass('ui-buttonset');
};

if( $("#myRadio").buttonsetIsInitialized() ){
  console.log('refresh element');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.20/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="myRadio">
  <input id="first" type="radio" value="1" name="steps"/><label for="first">First</label>
  <input id="second" type="radio" value="2" name="steps"/><label for="second">Second</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Is that not the answer you're looking for @leora ?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your item has a `data()` object item named `uiButtonset`:

```
function isButtonsetInitialized(item) {
    return (typeof $(item).data('uiButtonset') == 'object');
}
```

and then use it as

```
if(isButtonsetInitialized('#myradio')) {
  $('#myradio').buttonset('refresh');
}
```

check out this working example.

```js
function isButtonsetInitialized(item) {
  return (typeof $(item).data('uiButtonset') == 'object');
}

$(function() {
  console.log(isButtonsetInitialized('#test_1'));
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('input[type="radio"]').button().buttonset();
    console.log(isButtonsetInitialized('#test_1'));
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test_1" value="1" />
<label for="test_1">FIRST</label>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test_2" value="2" />
<label for="test_2">SECOND</label>
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test_3" value="3" />
<label for="test_3">THIRD</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use jquery ui anymore - I moved to jquery mobile but I hope I can help...

Important: I assume you already know that buttonset is deprecated?

From http://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/

> This widget is deprecated, use [Controlgroup](http://api.jqueryui.com/controlgroup/%20Controlgroup) instead.

If forced to continue with [buttonset](http://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/), then http://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/ references class "ui-buttonset". Basically, I would seek if this class exists or does not exist somewhere around your selector. Failing that, I would examine what classes are set pre/post button set, and use that as a reference.

Sorry I cannot offer a more accurate suggested solution.

```
if( ! $("#myRadio").parent().find("ui-buttonset") )
{
    $("#myRadio").buttonset('refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use the [instance method](https://api.jqueryui.com/jquery.widget/#method-instance) of the jQuery ui widget factory.

> Retrieves the widget's instance object. If the element does not have an associated instance, undefined is returned.

Here is an example:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#button-group-initiated').buttonset();

  console.log(
    "Button set one instanced? > " + $('#button-group-initiated').buttonset("instance")
  )

  console.log(
    "Button set two instanced? > " + $('#button-group-woot').buttonset("instance")
  )
});
```

```css
body > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div>
  <div id="button-group-initiated">
    <input type="radio" id="sizzle" name="project">
    <label for="sizzle">Sizzle</label>

    <input type="radio" id="qunit" name="project" checked="checked">
    <label for="qunit">QUnit</label>

    <input type="radio" id="color" name="project">
    <label for="color">Color</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="button-group-woot">
    <input type="radio" id="sizzle2" name="project2">
    <label for="sizzle2">Sizzle</label>

    <input type="radio" id="qunit2" name="project2" checked="checked">
    <label for="qunit2">QUnit</label>

    <input type="radio" id="color2" name="project2">
    <label for="color2">Color</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a much elegant solution using builtin event `buttonsetcreate` of buttonset. Alternatively you can use callback event of the buttonset. All described here https://api.jqueryui.com/buttonset/#event-create

This event will allow you whenever the buttonset initiated, you can do whatever you want with it. No need to check again and again to see if it is init or not. Just put your code in `event` and be done.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/ergec/wk9ew1bp/

**html**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Favorite jQuery Project</legend>
    <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="sizzle" name="project">
        <label for="sizzle">Sizzle</label>

        <input type="radio" id="qunit" name="project" checked="checked">
        <label for="qunit">QUnit</label>

        <input type="radio" id="color" name="project">
        <label for="color">Color</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
<button id="initbuttonset">Init</button>
<button id="checkbuttonset">Check</button>
```

**js**

```
var isbuttonsetinit = false;
$("#radio").on("buttonsetcreate", function(event, ui) {
    isbuttonsetinit = true;
    alert("buttonset init");
});
$("#initbuttonset").click(function() {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
});
$("#checkbuttonset").click(function() {
    alert(isbuttonsetinit);
});
```

**js (alternative)**

```
var isbuttonsetinit = false;
$("#initbuttonset").click(function() {
    $("#radio").buttonset({create: function( event, ui ) {
        isbuttonsetinit = true;
        alert("buttonset init");
    }});
});
$("#checkbuttonset").click(function() {
    alert(isbuttonsetinit);
});
```